# Typing properties of Jasmine userContext (using TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

How can I provide type to property set on Jasmine's `userContext` in `beforeEach()` function ?

My code:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
   this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
     AppHttp,
     { provide: WarningStore, useClass: MockWarningStore },
     { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
     { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
   ]);

  this.service = this.injector.get(AppHttp) as AppHttp;
 });
```

Unfortunately the type of `this.service` is `any`.

Can I somehow cast type of `this.service` to `AppHttp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` shouldn't be used in Jasmine tests in conjunction with arrow functions. It will get wrong context (either `window` or suite context, depending on `describe` block). `this` should be used [with regular functions](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-The_%3Ccode%3Ethis%3C/code%3E_keyword), this way it can be specific to particular test and be properly typed:

```
interface FooTest {
  service: AppHttp,
  ...
}

beforeEach(function (this: FooTest) {
  this.injector = ...
  ...
});
```

In ES6 and TS testing local variables are usually used with arrows:

```
let injector;

beforeEach(() => {
  injector = ...
  ...
});
```